# Python lookup dict and nested values in dict_keys and swap value

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I'm attempting to swap values in dictionary(dic_map) with values from dictionary(B), where dic_map[key] = B. to give me a new dict with the values from B e.g

```
dic_map = {
    'Name': 'name',
    'Id': 'guid',
    'address':{
        'address1': 'road',
        'address2': 'road_nr',
        'address3': 'zipcode',
        'address4': 'city'
    },
    'tax': True,
    'isValid': False,
    'specific': 1,
    'credit': 200
}


B = {
    'name': 'Michael Jackson',
    'guid': '032-567-781',
    'road': 'The greatest Dr',
    'road_nr': 42,
    'zipcode': 90210,
    'city': 'Hollywood',
    'country': 'USA'
}
```

And the final dict

```
desired_result = {
    'Name': 'Michael Jackson',
    'Id': '032-567-781',
    'address':{
        'address1': 'The greatest Dr',
        'address2': 42,
        'address3': 90210,
        'address4': 'Hollywood',
    },
    'tax': True,
    'isValid': False,
    'specific': 1,
    'credit': 200
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
def swap_values(dic_values, dic_map):
    d = {}
    for k1 in dic_values.keys():
        for k2 in dic_map.keys():
            if k1 == dic_map[k2]:
                d[k2]=dic_values[k1]
            else:
                d[k2]=dic_map[k2]
    return d
```

There are 2 things that is not working as far as I can tell, 1. my values gets overwritten by the else statement, and 2. the nested dict is never evaluated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this would be easiest with recursion

Comment: This is unrelated, but you can just iterate directly over the `dict` if you want to iterate over the keys. Also, don't *iterate* over your `dic_values`, that defeats the purpose of having a `dict`. But yeah, you sohould probably just recurse over nested dicts.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the track with recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are inner dicts, we must repeat the replacement operation for every inner dict. The easiest way to perform that kind of task is using recursion.

Validating type is not considered very *pythonic*, but it will get the job done. You can do something like this:

```
def swap_values(dic_values, dic_map):
    d = {}

    for k, v in dic_values.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = swap_values(v, dic_map)
        else:
            d[k] = dic_map.get(v, v)

    return d
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> dic_map = {
...     'Name': 'name',
...     'Id': 'guid',
...     'address':{
...         'address1': 'road',
...         'address2': 'road_nr',
...         'address3': 'zipcode',
...         'address4': 'city'
...     },
...     'tax': True,
...     'isValid': False,
...     'specific': 1,
...     'credit': 200
... }
>>> 
>>> 
>>> B = {
...     'name': 'Michael Jackson',
...     'guid': '032-567-781',
...     'road': 'The greatest Dr',
...     'road_nr': 42,
...     'zipcode': 90210,
...     'city': 'Hollywood',
...     'country': 'USA'
... }
>>> swap_values(dic_map, B)
{'specific': 1, 'Name': 'Michael Jackson', 'credit': 200, 'address': {'address1': 'The greatest Dr', 'address2': 42, 'address4': 'Hollywood', 'address3': 90210}, 'isValid': False, 'tax': True, 'Id': '032-567-781'}
```

If there were no inner dicts, we could use:

```
def swap_values(dic_values, dic_map):
    d = {}

    for k, v in dic_values.items():
        d[k] = dic_map.get(v, v)

    return d
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> dic_map = {
...     'Name': 'name',
...     'Id': 'guid',
...     'tax': True,
...     'isValid': False,
...     'specific': 1,
...     'credit': 200
... }
>>> 
>>> 
>>> B = {
...     'name': 'Michael Jackson',
...     'guid': '032-567-781',
...     'road': 'The greatest Dr',
...     'road_nr': 42,
...     'zipcode': 90210,
...     'city': 'Hollywood',
...     'country': 'USA'
... }
>>> swap_values(dic_map, B)
{'specific': 1, 'isValid': False, 'Name': 'Michael Jackson', 'Id': '032-567-781', 'tax': True, 'credit': 200}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
def dmap(template, values):
    for key, val in template.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            dmap(val, values)
        else:
            if val in values:
                template[key] = values[val]
```

If I run `dmap(dic_map, B)` I get:

```
{
  'Id': '032-567-781',
  'Name': 'Michael Jackson',
  'address': {
    'address1': 'The greatest Dr',
    'address2': 42,
    'address3': 90210,
    'address4': 'Hollywood'
  },
  'credit': 200,
  'isValid': False,
  'specific': 1,
  'tax': True
}
```